# Sort while appending to slice?

Tags: arrays, sorting, go

I have a `[]byte` which I need to sort, in ascending order.

I get an object with the items and then iterate the array in order to create the object returned:

```
// unfortunately, for some obscure reason I can't change the data types of the caller and the object from the function call are different, although both are []byte underneath (...)

type ID []byte
// in another package:
type ByteInterface []byte


func (c *Store) GetAll() ByteInterface {
  returnObj := make([]ByteInterface,0)
  obj, err := GetData()
  // err handling
  for _, b := range obj.IDs {
     returnObj = append(returnObj, ByteInterface(b))
  }
  return returnObj
}
```

So I'm asking myself if it is possible to do the `append` so that `returnObj` is sorted right away, or if I need to sort `obj.ByteData` upfront (or sort `returnOjb` afterwards).

Comment: If you know the index it should be placed in, sure (see https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#insert). But there is no magic to keep a slice sorted while appending to it (there's little magic in Go at all, in fact.)

Comment: You have a `[][]byte` you need to sort. How do you wish to sort? Lexicographically? Do you need to support UTF-8? What does ascendingly mean in this context? Do you want to sort the first or the second dimension(s)? This question is confusing.

Comment: @thwd actually `ByteInterface` is sortable. The `[]byte` are hex addresses, so in alphabetical ascending order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On each iteration, do the following:

1. Grow the target slice (possibly reallocating it):

   ```
   numElems := len(returnObj)
   returnObj = append(returnObj, make([]byte, len(obj))...)
   ```
2. Use the standard approach for insertion to keep the destination sorted by finding a place to put each byte from the source slice, one by one:

   ```
   for _, b := range obj {
     i := sort.Search(numElems, func (i int) bool {
       return returnObj[i] >= b
     }
     if i < numElems {
       copy(returnObj[i+1:], returnObj[i:])
     }
     returnObj[i] = b
     numElems++
   }
   ```

   (The call to `copy` should be optimized by copying less but this is left as an exercise for the reader.)

Comment: Nice job. I wonder though if this extra work is worth instead of just sorting afterwards with normal sorting (`ByteInterface` is sortable).

But it answers my question so I will accept it

Comment: @faboolous the real question is whether or not the extra code complexity is worth whatever gains may be achieved. Or if you're willing to accept that some random dev down the line may (i.e.) decide it's a good idea to switch the first two elements of the existing slice being append-sorted to, which breaks the assumption that a sorted slice always comes out the other end if a non-empty slice is appended to.